# how to get a Noisy edge in Blender 2.8/2.9 Cycles or Eevee

Tags: effects

I am trying to recreate a few animations using 3d. There is a certain technique in After Effects which I love which is to give your 2d vector shapes a kind of a noisy edge so it isn't so clean.

See Video here for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnW69.jpg

obviously I can keep doing this in AfterEffects but I am trying to learn the extent of what is possible in blender.

Is there a way to add such a noisy edge to 3d Shape? Either compositing? Directly on the mesh (i assume this may take longer to process? or something in between?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cycles you can change the material settings > displacement to something else than *Bump* to actually change the geometry:

[image]

Then you can pass something like noise to the displacement:

[image]

Not only Cycles requirement is possibly very expensive, but sometimes you also need to subdivide your geometry for more resolution of the displacement (on the right):

[image]  [image]

You can see the inside is changed as well, though it's unclear if it's a problem in your case, as the example you provided has a single color - you could say it's shadeless:

[image]  [image]

Other than that, you could use Freestyle to draw a line and then use a separate freestyle pass to remove alpha from the render around its edges (keep in mind it will not interact with the shading of the object, e.g. messing up Fresnel highlights), or You could use Normal (Fresnel/Layer Weight) to control alpha of the material...

[image]

[image] [image]

Also, geometry nodes...

Of course you can animate the noise texture and therefore the effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right I don't need the centers objects to be noisy but mostly where different Materials meet. For example Material A has a border with Material B on the same Mesh Object, I would expect both Materials to have a noisy edge. 

I am going to review all the methods you outlined and try to figure out the best fit. let you know. Thanks again.